Teams message extension query not working on iOS for new conversations
Im currently developing a Teams message extension that uses the query command on startup and if the user is not logged in it will show Sign-In card.
If I enter an existent chat and open my message extension everything works fine, the bod node-backend receives the events and a "Sign-In" card we implemented is returned.
But if I start a new conversation with no interaction previously done and try the same flow not a single log is fired on the node-backend indicating any event (even when I type and enter a search query text)
The weird thing is that it works fine on my windows/Mac teams app and only fails on iOS (currently testing on iOS 17.3.1)
// manifest.json
// ...composeExtensions array content
[{
  "id": "searchInput",
  "context": [
    "compose",
    "commandBox"
  ],
  "description": "Search for a place",
  "title": "My Places",
  "type": "query",
  "initialRun": true,
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "search",
      "title": "Search Place",
      "description": "Type to search a place",
      "inputType": "text"
    }
  ]
}]

Is there any existent fix or known issue tracked for this?
I have tried to add multiple handlers inside the bot message adapter to see if anything at all was reaching the back-end when triggered from iOS on an empty new conversation, but no handler was reached.

Could you please let us know what you mean by starting a new conversation with no interaction previously done? How are you creating the new conversation?

It happens when I search for someone on my contacts list that I didn't have any previous conversation, select them to start our first chat and instead of typing anything I first try to use the message extension.

We are also able to repro this issue, we will check internally and get back to you.

We raised a bug for this, we will keep you posted on the updates. Thank you.
